# how to train a naiveBayes model with Libsvm dataset format like Mnist?

Tags: r, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I downloaded Mnist data here and its forart is like below https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html#mnist

```
$ head -1 mnist
5 153:3 154:18 155:18 156:18 157:126 158:136 159:175 160:26 161:166 162:255 163:247 164:127 177:30 178:36 179:94 180:154 181:170 182:253 183:253 184:253 185:253 186:253 187:225 188:172 189:253 190:242 191:195 192:64 204:49 205:238 206:253 207:253 208:253 209:253 210:253 211:253 212:253 213:253 214:251 215:93 216:82 217:82 218:56 219:39 232:18 233:219 234:253 235:253 236:253 237:253 238:253 239:198 240:182 241:247 242:241 261:80 262:156 263:107 264:253 265:253 266:205 267:11 269:43 270:154 290:14 291:1 292:154 293:253 294:90 320:139 321:253 322:190 323:2 348:11 349:190 350:253 351:70 377:35 378:241 379:225 380:160 381:108 382:1 406:81 407:240 408:253 409:253 410:119 411:25 435:45 436:186 437:253 438:253 439:150 440:27 464:16 465:93 466:252 467:253 468:187 494:249 495:253 496:249 497:64 519:46 520:130 521:183 522:253 523:253 524:207 525:2 545:39 546:148 547:229 548:253 549:253 550:253 551:250 552:182 571:24 572:114 573:221 574:253 575:253 576:253 577:253 578:201 579:78 597:23 598:66 599:213 600:253 601:253 602:253 603:253 604:198 605:81 606:2 623:18 624:171 625:219 626:253 627:253 628:253 629:253 630:195 631:80 632:9 649:55 650:172 651:226 652:253 653:253 654:253 655:253 656:244 657:133 658:11 677:136 678:253 679:253 680:253 681:212 682:135 683:132 684:16
```

Then I tried R naiveBayes package, but got error

> naiveBayes formula interface handles data frames or arrays only

below is what I did:

Load R interface: ./bin/sparkR --master "local[2]"

```
> training <- loadDF(sqlContext, "~/Downloads/mnist", "libsvm")

> training
SparkDataFrame[label:double, features:vector]

> head(training)
  label                      features
1     0 <environment: 0x7fa8ef236630>
2     1 <environment: 0x7fa8edc3d708>
3     1 <environment: 0x7fa8edc561b8>
4     1 <environment: 0x7fa8edc6aa30>
5     1 <environment: 0x7fa8edc72aa0>
6     0 <environment: 0x7fa8edc79ab0>

> model <- naiveBayes(label ~ features, training)

Error in naiveBayes.formula(label ~ features, training) :
  naiveBayes formula interface handles data frames or arrays only
```

I guess it's because the "feature" is vector type and R cannot parse it. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or how to handle the vector type in R to get a naiveBayes model properly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if you call as.data.frame() on training, then run naiveBayes?

Comment: `> training <- loadDF(sqlContext, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt", "libsvm")
> tt <- as.data.frame(training)
> tt
    label                      features
1       0 <environment: 0x7fa8ee11a270>
2       1 <environment: 0x7fa8edf98340>
3       1 <environment: 0x7fa8edf9e8a0>`

Comment: then "feature" is still object, where I guess it's supposed to be an array

Comment: but if I read in as "json" or "csv", it seems working for me. but "libsvm" is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue here, when building naiveBayes model. I imported R package for naiveBayes by `library(e1071)`

But if R package, then I should somehow convert the `> training SparkDataFrame[label:double, features:vector]` to a R recognizable data format which is array or data frames.

When I switch to spark built-in method `spark.naiveBayes()` to build model, then it's **generating the model successfully** as follows:

```
model <- spark.naiveBayes(training, label ~ features)
```

since built-in `spark.naiveBayes()` comes in couple with `SparkDataFrame` type